# Node.JS - Select Max() result is not defined

Tags: javascript, android, mysql, node.js

I'm, trying to make a call from my backend where I think I have to use **Select MAX(column_name + 1)** so that I will have a new value at that column and then show/display it the same time in my front-end.

> ( I will have to use it to generate a new Order Number )

But the problem is, whenever I call it in my browser to check my output it is not defined. Even in Postman.

**I use Node.JS, Express-Generator and React Native**

Here is my code

OrderNo.js (models)

```
var db=require('../dbconnection');

var Task = {
    getTaskById:function(callback){
        return db.query("Select MAX(order_no + 1) from orders",callback,result);
    },
}

module.exports=Task;
```

OrderNo.js (routes)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Task = require('../models/OrderNo')

router.get('/order_no', (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.params){
        Task.getTaskById(req.params,function(err,rows){    
            if(err)
            {
                res.json(err);
            }
            else{
                res.json(rows);
            }
        });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

The errors:

[image: Browser]

[image: Nodemon]

[image: Postman]

Comment: Try `(MAX(column) + 1) AS max_plus1` instead off `MAX(column_name + 1)`

Comment: Is max_plus1 is an alias sir? if yes, should I declare it somewhere in my code? I'm sorry, this is my first time to use select max() and I'm not that advance in nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `result` variable in `return db.query("Select MAX(order_no + 1) from orders",callback,result);` is not defined in that file.  What you're seeing in a javascript execution error as the interpreter fails to find the undefined variable "result", not a MySQL error.